# Fragment savedInstanceState not null after activity killed by OS

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have a fragment which saves the state via `setRetainInstance(true)`. This is my fragment's very simplified code:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
  private SomeData mData;

  public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        mData = new SomeData(getView());
      } else {
        mData.refresh(getView());
      }
      // More awesome code
    }
  }
}
```

Sometimes the app crashes with `NullPointerException` - my `mData` suddenly becomes `null`. This happens when I fold the application and return after some time.

I have some theory. After a while OS kills the `Activity` and the `Fragment` (despite `setRetainInstance (true)`). Thus creates a new object of my fragment where `mData` initialized by `null`. But `savedInstanseState` not equals to null. Thus the new fragment skips initialization and attempts to call `refresh(View)` on the null reference.

My question:
What will contain the `savedInstanseState` variable in the `onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)` method in my snippet when OS kills the activity (when app not on the screen) and recreate after return?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the answer fully but here it is What I can guess

> setRetainInstance (boolean retain) Control whether a fragment instance
>   is retained across Activity re-creation (such as from a configuration
>   change). **This can only be used with fragments not in the back stack.**

So I think that When you fold the activity the views get destroyed and instance data (setReetainInstance value)is saved in the bundle ( making savedInstanceState != null while loading). However, when you load the activity (since previously the retainInstance was set to true) onCreate() does not get called and since savedInstanceState != null and mData == null you get the error.